# Lookup for MULTIPLE values and return a specific cell if AT LEAST ONE criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, lookup

I am trying to find a specific value (from multiple options) in an array (Please, see the picture below). I tried several formulas, playing with OR, HLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH, but I couldn't find a working formula yet. It is all good if I look for a single value, but as soon as I add multiple criteria I get #VALUE or #N/A, or similar errors.

Could you be so kind to help me out with this matter?

MyData:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Borehole | Week1 | Week2 | Week3 | Week4 |  | Wanted output: |
| ML 110 | 06/10/2021 | W 01/11 |  |  |  | ML 110 |
| ML 111 | W 18/10 |  |  |  |  | ML 111 |
| ML 114 | W 25/10 |  |  |  |  | ML 114 |
| ML 117 | 10/10/2021 | 11/11/2021 | W 06/12 |  |  |  |
| ML 119 | W 08/11 |  |  |  |  | ML 119 |
| ML 120 | 25/10/2021 | W 01/11 |  |  |  | ML 120 |
| ML 129 | 19/09/2021 | 22/10/2021 | 05/11/2021 | W 06/12 |  |  |

| I | J | K | L | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lookup Values: | W 18/10 | W 25/10 | W 01/11 | W 08/11 |

[Excel setting and question explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KncfL.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can use MATCH to test if it exists in the lookup row:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:E2,$J$1:$M$1,0))),A2,"")
```

[image]